# Is there a best practice for showing database changes on a JSP

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jsp

We need to show database changes on a JSP page. The Information in the Database is changed by a legacy System, so I don’t have any change to get an event on Data change. So the problem is to keep the Database Information and the JSP Page in sync.

Our first approach is to poll the Database and synchronizing the data with an Application bean. If the data has changed, we use a push mechanism to update the JSP page.

This approach Works but somehow I am not sure if it’s a good approach.

We are using a MS-SQL Database and a Tomcat as Servlet Container.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPA you could try Entity listeners and Callbacks. There are few annotations for methods(like PreRemove) which which you can use for tracking all changes you need. See this article http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html

Comment: The OP said: *The Information in the Database is changed by a legacy System, so I don’t have any change to get an event on Data change*

Comment: Unfortunately we're not using JPA.